# which parameters effects the position of hyper plane in SVM and how?

Tags: python, svm

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tQMEx.png)

```py
ratios = [(100,2), (100, 20), (100, 40), (100, 80)]

c_list = [0.001, 1, 100] #list of different values regularizier

for j,i in enumerate(ratios): 

    plt.figure(figsize=(18,14))
    X_p=np.random.normal(0,0.05,size=(i[0],2))
    X_n=np.random.normal(0.13,0.02,size=(i[1],2))
    y_p=np.array([1]*i[0]).reshape(-1,1)
    y_n=np.array([0]*i[1]).reshape(-1,1)
    X=np.vstack((X_p,X_n))
    y=np.vstack((y_p,y_n))
    for a in range(len(c_list)):
        plt.subplot(4,3,a+1)
        clf = SVC(C=c_list[a],kernel='linear', degree=3,probability=False, tol=0.001, cache_size = 200, class_weight=None, verbose=2, max_iter=1000, decision_function_shape='ovr', random_state=15)
        clf.fit(X=X,y=y)
        coef = clf.coef_
        intercept = clf.intercept_
        y_max = np.amax(y)
        y_min = np.amin(y)

        X_pos = np.empty((i[0],2))

        X_neg = np.empty((i[1],2))
        l= 0
        m =0
        for r in range(len(X)):
            if y[r]==1:
                X_pos[l] = X[r]
                l +=1
            else:
                X_neg[m]= X[r]
                m +=1

        plt.scatter(X_pos[:, 0], X_pos[:, 1],color = 'blue')
        plt.scatter(X_neg[:, 0], X_neg[:, 1],color = 'red')
        hyper_plane = draw_hyper_plane(coef,intercept,y_max,y_min)
    plt.show()


def draw_hyper_plane(coef,intercept,y_max,y_min):

            points=np.array([[((-coef[0][1]*y_min - intercept)/coef[0][0]), y_min],[((-coef[0][1]*y_max - intercept)/coef[0][0]), y_max]])
            plt.plot(points[:,0], points[:,1])
```

i want to know what factors effect the position of hyper plane ?
how can improve the position of hyper plane?

Answer (score 0):

The `C` parameter is the regularization parameter, and it has a lot of influence here. The imbalanced classes too. When `svm` is iteratively moving the hyperplane to find the optimal position, the regularization term *penalizes* the coefficients when it misclassifies an example. It does so by moving a great step back in the right direction, but with a large regularization value (100), it can bounce way too far (as you can see in your first plot).

This is exacerbated with the imbalanced classes, because the majority class will have more weight. As you can see, as the regularization parameter decreases, it becomes more stable.

Moral of the story: start with default regularization values, and move from there. Btw, this is a post better suited for https://stats.stackexchange.com.